# Can I add elements of a superalgebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, superalgebra

Let's consider a superalgebra $A$ over the real numbers $\mathbb R$. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superalgebra) defines this superalgebra via the direct sum:
$$ A = A_0 \oplus A_1, \tag{1} $$
and a bilinear multiplication (indices mod 2):
$$ A_i A_j \subseteq A_{i+j}.  $$
An element $x\in A_i$ has parity $|x|=i$.
If we let $x,y\in A_0$ and $\theta,\eta\in A_1$, then:
$$ xy=yx, \quad \theta\eta =-\eta\theta, \quad x\theta = \theta x. \tag{3} $$
My question is: can we take the sum of two elements belonging to different $A_i$? In other words, does "$x + \theta$" make sense?

Comment: Do you understand what the symbol $\oplus$ means?

Comment: @runway44 Sure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does. If $x\in A_0$ and $\theta\in A_1$, then $x+\theta\in A_0\oplus A_1$. If $x+\theta$ didn't exist, $A$ wouldn't even be a vector space, and much less an algebra.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!